# What is length to points conversione formula in Wormax?

Tags: wormax.io

[wormax.io](http://www.wormax.io) is a clone of [slither.io](http://www.slither.io) (with lots of annoying ads).
When you lose the wormax online game, you receive some points. I still didn't find the formula that converts length to points. Here there is an example list of some length and points pairs:

```
Lenght -> Score
418    -> 0
1818   -> 1
2988   -> 1
4000   -> 2
7318   -> 3
8506   -> 3
13031  -> 5
21374  -> 7
28143  -> 10
31895  -> 11
64811  -> 22
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Score=ROUNDDOWN((lenght+2000)/3000))
```